# React Native keyboardType: numeric allows the letter 'e'

Tags: react-native

*e* is able to be input on the numeric keyboard

Looking for keyboard type that only allows integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make it so the value only gets updated when an integer is typed:

```
this.state = {
  numberInput: '',
}
...
handleChangeText = (numberInput) => {
  if (Number.isInteger(+numberInput)) {
    this.setState({ numberInput });
  }
}
...
<TextInput
  value={this.state.numberInput}
  onChangeText={this.handleChangeText}
  style={...}
/>
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.
Thank you!